# How to change the keys of existing arrays to unique values using a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm trying to combine the feeds from two separate API's into one, but first I need to ensure that the feeds contain the same keys so I can merge the two together. Within a for each loop, I am storing the values I wish to keep for each array, however, I would like for each value to have a unique key instead of the classic [0], [1], [2], etc. numbering system. How would I get $value3 to have a unique string key for each value it holds?

```
$googleArray = array();

foreach ($myEvents as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        // Remove unnecessary keys from google API arrays
        unset($value2[method], $value2[kind], $value2[status], $value2[htmlLink], $value2[created], $value2[updated], $value2[colorId], $value2[creator],$value2[organizer],$value2[iCalUID],$value2[sequence],$value2[reminders], $value2[etag],$value2[id],$value2[minutes]);

        //Make new keys for googleArray in order to store each list to its designated event

        $googleArray[$key2] = $value2;  

        // foreach ($value2 as $key3[summary] => $value3) {
            // Store desired values in new array
            // $googleArray[] = $value3;
        // }
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to get

```
$key2["summary"] = $key2["DESC1"];
```

The summary key to become the key DESC1

Comment: Unrelated to your question, you need to set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of your script or [in your PHP configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) during development. When you do, you'll see that e.g. `$value2[kind]`, throws an error, because you're trying to use a constant (`kind`) when no constant with those name exists. PHP corrects this for you, but it hurts your application's performance a lot. Increasing your `error_reporting` level to `E_ALL` will let you see all of the errors and correct your code (in this case, by using `$value2['kind']` instead).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly (it's a bit difficult to develop from the information provided), I think you just need to declare an array that maps the original `$key2` value to the new name you want it to have in `$googleArray`, and then do a lookup in that mapping to get the desired keyname at insertion time. e.g.,

```
$mapping = ['DESC1' => 'summary', 'DESC2' => 'foo'];
foreach(...) {
  foreach(...) {
    ...

    $googleArray[$mapping[$key2]] = $value2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$googleArray = array();

foreach($myEvents as $key=>$value){

    if ( in_array($value['googleArray'], $googleArray) ) {

        continue;
    }

    $googleArray[] = $value['googleArray'];

    echo $value['googleArray'];

}
```

Comment: kindly avoid code only anser and explain them a bit